# how to get access of my button in one of my viewpager pages?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm new to this android and java.

My viewpager now can slide all my xml layout, but i don't know how to access item in them.

I tried using `Button mybutton = (Button) findViewById (R.layout.result)`, then set the `onClickListener` in mybutton, but then it was forced to close every time I run it.

Here is my code:

```
public class main extends Activity {

    private ViewPager myviewpager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter myviewpageradapter;
    private static int NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS = 12;
    Button button_1;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myviewpageradapter = new ViewPagerAdapter();
        myviewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);
        myviewpager.setAdapter(myviewpageradapter);

            button_1 = (Button) myviewpager.findViewById(R.id.first_button);
            button_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    }

    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
                return NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
                LayoutInflater layoutinflater = getLayoutInflater();

                View view;
                view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, null);

                switch (position)
                {
                    case 0 : view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, null); break;
                    case 1 : view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, null); break;
                    case 2 : view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.page3, null); break;
                    case 3 : view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.page4, null); break;
                    case 4 : view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.page5, null); break;
                    case 5 : view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.page6, null); break;
                    case 6 : view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.page7, null); break;
                    case 7 : view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.page8, null); break;
                    case 8 : view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.page9, null); break;
                    case 9 : view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.page10, null); break;
                    case 10 : view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.page11, null); break;
                    case 11 : view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.result, null);break;
                }
                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view,0);
                return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
                ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
        }



        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view==((View)object);
        }

        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {}


        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {}

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void startUpdate(View arg0) {}

    }
```

Comment: I have the same problem. If you use the debugger you will see that the code inside the PageAdapter is launched at some point before anything is drawn on the screen, so the `findViewById` that you are trying just after the `.setAdapter` will return null.
Please someone tell us how the lifecycle of a pagerAdapter works, so we can access the views inside it. thanks!

Comment: kaizie..do you find anything ??

Comment: try: `myviewpager.findViewById(resId);`

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, Did anyone find the solution??

Answer (score 2):

It may just be the Problem, that your items are not found probably so try this(If your view is no LinearLayout change it)

```
LayoutInflater getView = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

LinearLayout view1 =(LineaLayout)getView.inflate(R.layout.your_view,null);
```

But Your Button may throw Exception furthermore there is an onClickListener set to it.
If it's just the Button define it in XML:

```
android:onClick"buttonClick"
```

then in Code

```
public void buttonClick(View v){

// do something

}
```

If this is not possible because you need to reference the Button later, I stuck with the same Problem and would like to know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are trying to find a view (findViewById) that wasn't instatiated (inflated) yet. Try to set the button listener inside the instatiateItem method of ViewPagerAdapter type.

Example:

```
    switch(position){
    case 0 : 
    view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, null); 
    button_1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.first_button);
    button_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
               finish();
               }
         });
    break;
    (...)    
    }
```